# add calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript, addition

I have used this code for numeric addition. The only one problem is that it is not calculating expressions like (10 + 1.5 = 11 ). Why this code not calculating .5 value in total?

```
      <script>
      function calculate() {
       var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ORD_PRICE_1').value;    
       var myBox2 = document.getElementById('ORD_PRICE_2').value;
   var myBox3 = document.getElementById('ORD_PRICE_3').value;
       var result = document.getElementById('TOTAL');    
   var myResult = parseInt(myBox1) + parseInt(myBox2) + parseInt(myBox3);  
   result.value = myResult;


      }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you are using `parseInt()` which convert it into integer, instead try `parseFloat`:

```
var myResult = parseFloat(myBox1) + parseFloat(myBox2) + parseFloat(myBox3);
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/cFC9k/)

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` rounds off the decimal values hence not included in calculation. if you want to consider decimal into calculation then you must use `parseFloat()`

It should be like this.

```
 <script>
      function calculate() {
       var myBox1 = document.getElementById('ORD_PRICE_1').value;    
       var myBox2 = document.getElementById('ORD_PRICE_2').value;
   var myBox3 = document.getElementById('ORD_PRICE_3').value;
       var result = document.getElementById('TOTAL');    
   var myResult = parseFloat(myBox1) + parseFloat(myBox2) + parseFloat(myBox3);  
   result.value = myResult;


      }
     </script>
```